# rosjava_core not compiling with messsage error

Tags: ros, rosjava-core

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build rosjava_core using the command:

> ./gradlew install

and getting the following error output (only the seeming relevant error included):

> :rosjava_bootstrap:jar

> :rosjava_messages:generateSources

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No message definition available for: move_arm_msgs/MoveArmGoal
> at
> org.ros.internal.message.MessageDefinitionProviderChain.get(MessageDefinitionProviderChain.java:51)
> at org.ros.internal.message.DefaultMessageFactory.newFromType(DefaultMessageFactory.java:38)
> at org.ros.internal.message.MessageFieldType.getDefaultValue(MessageFieldType.java:41)
> at org.ros.internal.message.ScalarField.newValue(ScalarField.java:36)
> at org.ros.internal.message.MessageContext.addValueField(MessageContext.java:83)
> at org.ros.internal.message.MessageContextFactory$1.scalar(MessageContextFactory.java:55)
> at org.ros.internal.message.MessageDefinitionParser.parseField(MessageDefinitionParser.java:165)
> at org.ros.internal.message.MessageDefinitionParser.parse(MessageDefinitionParser.java:104)
> at org.ros.internal.message.MessageContextFactory.newFromMessageDeclaration(MessageContextFactory.java:73)
> at org.ros.internal.message.MessageInterfaceBuilder.build(MessageInterfaceBuilder.java:114)
> at org.ros.internal.message.GenerateInterfaces.writeServiceInterfaces(GenerateInterfaces.java:135)
> at org.ros.internal.message.GenerateInterfaces.generate(GenerateInterfaces.java:152)
> at org.ros.internal.message.GenerateInterfaces.main(GenerateInterfaces.java:170)

It should be noted that MoveArmGoal.java does exist in rosjava_messages.
Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31774/rosjava_core-not-compiling-with-messsage-error/) by [dfseifer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1721/dfseifer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, I figured out the problem. I had some code written for diamondback that had references to deprecated messages in my workspace. Creating a clean workspace, with only the electric stacks and none of my own code fixed the problem.

---

Originally posted by [dfseifer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1721/dfseifer/) with karma: 51 on 2012-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1